# $\mathbb{Q}(t+t^{-1}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(t)$, where $t$ is a variable

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let $\mathbb{Q}(t+t^{-1}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(t)$, where $t$ is a variable. Prove or disprove that $\mathbb{Q}(t) / \mathbb{Q}(t+t^{-1})$ is a Galois extension.

Any idea or hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT:** What is the degree of the extension?

**ANSWER:** Note that $t$ is a root of
$$(x-t)(x-t^{-1})=x^2-(t+t^{-1})x+1,$$
so the extension is of degree two and hence Galois.

Comment: Is it 2? $\mathbb{Q}(t+t^{-1}, t-t^{-1})=\mathbb{Q}(t)$ and$(t-t^{-1})^2=(t+t^{-1})-4$ so $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ is the splitting field of $x^2-(t-t^{-1})^2=x^2-(t+t^{-1})^2+4 \in \mathbb{Q}(t+t^{-1})[x]$.

Comment: Okay, the polynomial $x^2-(t-t^{-1})^2$ is separable. I think I got it. Thanks!

Comment: No; the splitting field of $x^2-(t-t^{-1})^2=(x-(t-t^{-1}))(x+(t-t^{-1}))$ is just $\Bbb{Q}(t+t^{-1})$. You are right that the degree is $2$, though, and you are not far from an answer.

Comment: i think $|{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}(t+t^{-1})}(\mathbb{Q}(t))|$=1<[E:F]=2 because every rational number is fixed so $t$ is maped itself. Am I right?

Comment: What about the automorphism mapping $t$ to $t^{-1}$?

Comment: @Andrew I see now that I misread your earlier comment; I mixed up $t-t^{-1}$ and $t+t^{-1}$. You were absolutely right.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!